# Including classloader resources starting with underscore (_) in an APK

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I have a library that reads a Classloader resource `properties/_message.properties`, though something like

```
this.getClass()
    .getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream(
        "properties/_message.properties")
```

In older (Maven-based) versions of the Android build pipeline this worked fine, but it does not work with the current Gradle tools.

I have tried including the file as a resource in my project, but it is only included in the APK if it does not start with an underscore:

If I have two files `src/main/resources/properties/message.properties` and `src/main/resources/properties/_message.properties`.

`build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    }
}
```

If I build the APK, it contains `properties/message.properties` and not `properties/_message.properties`. The former file is also accessible as a classloader resource.

Answer (score 0):

There are some long-standing bugs related to this, that either claim to be fixed but aren't, or are marked WONTFIX.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36911326
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36961705

The first issue includes a workaround that *"[extends] the build process to add any asset files with a parent directory starting with an underscore to the debug APK after it's first assembled, and then resign the APK with the new files"*.

In summary: you can either use a workaround, or rename your resources.